# Plotting multiple line charts with incomplete years

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a data set spanning 4 years that I'd like to plot on a chart, with each year as a separate series. My data is at a daily level of detail from March 2015 to August 2018, which I want to aggregate and display by month.

```
plt.clf() # clear figures
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8)) 

x = np.arange(0, 12, 1)
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
total_sales_2015 = train.loc[train['Year'] == '2015'].groupby('Month')['SalesValue'].sum()/1000.0 # format into thousands
total_sales_2016 = train.loc[train['Year'] == '2016'].groupby('Month')['SalesValue'].sum()/1000.0 # format into thousands
total_sales_2017 = train.loc[train['Year'] == '2017'].groupby('Month')['SalesValue'].sum()/1000.0 # format into thousands
total_sales_2018 = train.loc[train['Year'] == '2018'].groupby('Month')['SalesValue'].sum()/1000.0 # format into thousands

plt.plot(x, total_sales_2015, label="2015") <-- doesn't work, as only 10 data points
plt.plot(x, total_sales_2016, label="2016") <-- does work
plt.plot(x, total_sales_2017, label="2017") <-- does work
plt.plot(x, total_sales_2018, label="2018") <-- doesn't work, as only 8 data points
```

How can I show partial years on the graph? When I run the above code it produces the following error: "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension"

Comment: a couple of things: without sample data is hard to give accurate feedback. Secondly, if you group by month, having only 10 data points is not that absurd since you could be missing two months.

Comment: @Yuca: My data only goes back as far as March 2015, which is fine, I just want to compare the 10 monthly values I have from that year with subsequent years' values.

Comment: then why do you say it doesn't work ('as only 10 data points') when you're supposed to get 10 data points?

Comment: Because matplotlib expects the series to contain the same number of values as the x-axis, 12. When I run the code, I get "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension"

Comment: Just found the answer on another SO question.

Comment: @Jazza - Just added more dynamic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by all possible indices created by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
np.random.seed(123)
train = pd.DataFrame({'Year':['2015'] * 10 + ['2018'] * 8,
                      'Month': list(range(3, 13)) + list(range(1, 9)),
                      'SalesValue':np.random.randint(1000, size=18)})
train['Month'] = train['Month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
print (train)
    Year Month  SalesValue
0   2015    03         510
1   2015    04         365
2   2015    05         382
3   2015    06         322
4   2015    07         988
5   2015    08          98
6   2015    09         742
7   2015    10          17
8   2015    11         595
9   2015    12         106
10  2018    01         123
11  2018    02         569
12  2018    03         214
13  2018    04         737
14  2018    05          96
15  2018    06         113
16  2018    07         638
17  2018    08          47
```

---

```
total_sales = train.groupby(['Year','Month'])['SalesValue'].sum() / 1000

years = np.arange(2015, 2019).astype(str)
months = pd.Series(np.arange(1, 13, 1)).astype(str).str.zfill(2)

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([years, months], names=total_sales.index.names)

total_sales = total_sales.reindex(mux)
```

---

```
print (total_sales)

Year  Month
2015  01         NaN
      02         NaN
      03       0.510
      04       0.365
      05       0.382
      06       0.322
      07       0.988
      08       0.098
      09       0.742
      10       0.017
      11       0.595
      12       0.106
2016  01         NaN
      02         NaN
      03         NaN
      04         NaN
      05         NaN
      06         NaN
      07         NaN
      08         NaN
      09         NaN
      10         NaN
      11         NaN
      12         NaN
2017  01         NaN
      02         NaN
      03         NaN
      04         NaN
      05         NaN
      06         NaN
      07         NaN
      08         NaN
      09         NaN
      10         NaN
      11         NaN
      12         NaN
2018  01       0.123
      02       0.569
      03       0.214
      04       0.737
      05       0.096
      06       0.113
      07       0.638
      08       0.047
      09         NaN
      10         NaN
      11         NaN
      12         NaN
Name: SalesValue, dtype: float64
```

---

```
plt.plot(x, total_sales.loc['2015'], label="2015")
plt.plot(x, total_sales.loc['2016'], label="2016")
plt.plot(x, total_sales.loc['2017'], label="2017")
plt.plot(x, total_sales.loc['2018'], label="2018")
```

If possible values in `x-axis` are months use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8)) 
total_sales.unstack(level=0).plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue I had by appending `Nan` values to the start of the 2015 series and the end of the 2018 series as follows:

```
from numpy import nan
s1 = pd.Series([nan,nan], index=['01','02'])
s2 = pd.Series([nan,nan,nan,nan], index=['09', '10', '11', '12'])

total_sales_2015 = s1.append(total_sales_2015)
total_sales_2018 = total_sales_2018.append(s2)
```

Each series now has 12 data points, and can be plotted on the chart.